# Substring Function

Tags: sql, plsql

The output from a column is like this 'Arpit-Bansal-Doctor-ALC FU JP-111DC'.I want to extract the data which is between the `- -` that is for example `Bansal`.

Please advice which function to use and how to use.

Comment: And why not "Doctor"?  Or "Bansal-Doctor"?

Comment: Or why not `ALC FU JP`

Comment: Are you saying that the column value is a concatenation of 5 values delimited by hyphens, i.e. 'Arpit', 'Bansal', 'Doctor', 'ALC FU JP', '111DC', and that you want to get just the 2nd value?

Comment: Yes , you are right I want to extract all the values individually like : 1. Arpit2.Bansal,Doctor,

Comment: @TonyAndrews You are right but now I want to extract the values Individually making use of the hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the built-in functions [INSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions080.htm#SQLRF00651) and [SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions181.htm#SQLRF06114) like this:

```
select substr(col,instr(col,'-')+1,instr(col,'-',1,2)-instr(col,'-')-1) 
from (select 'Arpit-Bansal-Doctor-ALC FU JP-111DC' col from dual);
```

The INSTR function calls are used to find the first and second hyphen, and then SUBSTR is used to get the string between them.

This is quite cumbersome, so if you want all 5 values separated out and you are in PL/SQL you can use [apex_util.string_to_table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/apex_util.htm#CHDFEEJD) to separate them:

```
declare
   array apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
begin
   array := apex_util.string_to_table ('Arpit-Bansal-Doctor-ALC FU JP-111DC', '-');
   for i in 1..array.count loop
       dbms_output.put_Line ('Part' || i || ' is '||array(i));
   end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

```
select regexp_substr('Arpit-Bansal-Doctor-ALC FU JP-111DC', '[^-]+')
from dual;

Arpit

select regexp_substr('Arpit-Bansal-Doctor-ALC FU JP-111DC', '[^-]+', 1, 2)
from dual;

Bansal

select regexp_substr('Arpit-Bansal-Doctor-ALC FU JP-111DC', '[^-]+', 1, 3)
from dual;

Doctor

select regexp_substr('Arpit-Bansal-Doctor-ALC FU JP-111DC', '[^-]+', 1, 4)
from dual;

ALC FU JP
```